# Why is the derivative of the sigmoid function equivalent to x * (1 - x)?

Tags: derivatives, python, neural-networks

The sigmoid function is $\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$ and its derivative is $\sigma'(x) = \sigma(x) * (1 - \sigma(x))$.
In [this implementation](https://github.com/llSourcell/Make_a_neural_network/blob/master/demo.py) of a simple neural network I saw the derivative of the sigmoid function is being calculated as $\sigma'(x) = x * (1 - x)$, which doesn't look anything like the actual derivative, but works even better than the real derivative (at least in the XOR example).

I can't find anything on the internet describing why this function can be used instead of the actual derivative. Can anyone explain to me or point out a paper I should look at to gather a better understanding?

Comment: If you look at the think, train, and derivative methods, you will see that $x$ in the derivative method is actually the current function value (the output).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the code defines the sigmoid derivative as a function of $x$, if you look at where the function is actually called:

```
  # Multiply the error by the input and again by the gradient of the Sigmoid curve.
            # This means less confident weights are adjusted more.
            # This means inputs, which are zero, do not cause changes to the weights.
            adjustment = dot(training_set_inputs.T, error * self.__sigmoid_derivative(output))
```

so the input to the derivative function is the value of the output, i.e. it is applying $\sigma'(x) = \sigma(x)(1 - \sigma(x))$ correctly.